# Custom sized Modal View Swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to present a `modal` view controller, `presentedViewController`, via a storyboard segue in Swift, with a custom size, e.g `200 pixels by 200 pixels`.

`presentedViewController` is linked to a custom class, also called `presentedViewController`. In that class `viewDidLoad`, I used the following:

```
self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(200, 200)
```

It was intended that the modal view would be 200 pixels by 200 pixels, but it was normally sized.

In case it matters, the modal view is transparent, and presented `Over Current Context`.

Presenting as a popover similarly does not work.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried setting the view's Frame Size?  yourView.frame = CGRectMake(0 , 0, 200, 200)